# How to set padding and margin to all children elements to 0

Tags: jquery, css

Tried these two and they don't work. It seems something really simple but cannot find anything on this topic.

CSS:

```
#element * { padding: 0; margin 0; }
```

jQuery:

```
$("#element").children("*").css("padding", "0");
$("#element").children("*").css("margin", "0");
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First one should work just fine.. can you setup a demo on http://jsbin.com or something including your HTML

Comment: do u have an element with the ID element? otherwise that does nothing. 
If you want it on ALL elements, change your CSS to `body * { padding: 0; margin 0; }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use [.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) if you're going the jQuery route. .children only goes a single level deep.

`$('#element').find('*').css('padding', '0');`

http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/yg3CL/1/

Pure CSS:

```
body * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: As others have said, you can do this with pure css with `body * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }`, it just depends on how you want it to be done.  Are you just trying to remove padding/margins from elements by default?  If so, look into using a css normalize style sheet.

Comment: I wanted remove the padding & margin only to a certain div child element, I'm adding new elements inside the top div using .on() function, So I need to call this $('#element').find('*').css('padding', '0'); after each update. CSS doesn't work in this case I guess. Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you add a class to every element you want to remove the padding and margin from, css would work.  I don't know what your markup looks like, or how it's created, so I've been making some assumptions.

Answer (score 6):

Does this not work?

```
$("#element *").css("padding", "0");
$("#element *").css("margin", "0");
```

The `children` method only travels a single level down the DOM tree, so you will only be setting the css on the immediate descendants.  The `find` method would work however `$("#element")find('*').css("padding", "0");`